# Jenkins doesn't run as a deamon on Centos

Tags: jenkins

So, installed jenkins master on CentOS by following the steps on Jenkins.io website.

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
sudo chkconfig jenkins on
```

I didn't need to install java because I already had java 1.7 installed.

When i go to localhost:8080 it doesn't show up.  I rebooted the machine hoping that would start the deamon, but that didn't do it either.  When I go do `sudo service jenkins restart` FAILURE comes up for stop, but says "OK" for start.  Still doesn't show the site.  If I go to the /usr/lib/jenkins/ and then do java -jar jenkins.war it starts and i see the localhost:8080 site.

What am I missing?  Is it permissions issues?

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jenkins/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68843514 Jul  6 15:45 jenkins.war
```

Comment: Aside from my browser initially thinking that I wanted to go to www.localhost.com:8080 instead of localhost:8080; I sorted that out and am able to reach jenkins just fine. Unable to reproduce from your steps on CentOS 6.6.

Comment: If FAILURE is appearing during the stop phase of "restart", then Jenkins is probably failing to start. Check the Jenkins logs for errors.